# Can you express this orderly Palindromic Devil in strict ascending Pandigital form?

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, no-computers

Given:

Devil as you know is $ 666 $

Using digits 1 to 9 in strict ascending order and only three mathematical signs ( +, -, /, x ... of these are allowed), write the Pandigital expression

$ 666 =                 $

Comment: Parentheses or concatenation?

Comment: Concatenated Numbers only..no other operators other than specified

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that concatenation is allowed

> $1234 – 567 + 8 – 9 = 666$ 
>  (using three signs: -, + and -)

Answer (score 4):

Here's one:

> $666=123+456+78+9$

---

(I initially thought this was one, but the restriction being made is to use three operation instances, rather than three of the set of allowed operations)

> $666=123+45-6+7\times 8\times 9$

Comment: Only 3 mathematical signs permitted as per the puzzle

Comment: yeah plus, minus and multiply.

Comment: Oh only three *instances* ?

Comment: Found one using three instances and updated.